# Why isn't ! (not) overloaded?

Tags: java

It seems that

```
!
```

is used for boolean operands

and

```
~
```

is used for integer types to do a btitwise negation.

Why not just overload `!` to work with integer types as well?

I'm assuming there is a deeper reason than because "the spec says so"

For example `&` is overloaded to handle both integer types and boolean types with no problem.

Comment: I don't think I've seen `!` used for bitwise negation in any language, could be wrong?

Comment: @Joni - integer types can also represent a series of bits, I take it you are not familiar with bitwise `&` either?

Comment: It's probably just what Kevin said: in other languages `!` might have a different meaning on integers (e.g. when boolean values can also be represented as integers) and thus `~` is used for bitwise negation - and why change syntax that developers are already used to?

Comment: Yeah if I saw `(!intVar)` I'd probably read it as does `intVar` equal 0 and returning a bool rather than returning a bitwise negated int.

Comment: It is not clear what you would have !intValue do.

Comment: it should be clear, if you read the tag, this is Java, not JavaScript.  Java can do something called bitwise negation and it applies to all integer types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Likely reason (read pure speculation).

Java came after c and c++.

In c/c++ ! on integers has a meaning that is not bitwise negation.

The Java developers did not want to make it hard for the people converting from c/c++ to Java.

Comment: +1 My guess would be the same. Java was clearly aimed at C/C++ devs.

Comment: Yes, C/C++: `if (!n) { /* n==0 */ }`.